# How can I pull the SSL certificate from a remote server?

Tags: ssl-certificate

As the title says.  I need to use it to work around an SSL error I am getting in my application.

Comment: you don't, unless you're an admin of the server. pulling the cert would allow you to impersonate that server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with openssl via terminal, [this question has actually been asked over on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/139728/how-to-download-ssl-certificate-from-a-website).

> In order to download the certificate, you need to use the client built into openssl like so:
>
> echo -n | openssl s_client -connect HOST:PORTNUMBER | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/$SERVERNAME.cert
>
> That will save the certificate to /tmp/$SERVERNAME.cert.
>
> You can use -showcerts if you want to download all the certificates in the chain. But if you just want to download the server certificate, there is no need to specify -showcerts
>
> echo -n gives a response to the server, so that the connection is released
>
> sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' removes information about the certificate chain. This is the preferred format to import the certificate into other keystores.